# Can No-SQL be used on the xbox 360 with xna and c# or vb.net?

Tags: c#, database, xna

I was wondering is their a dll library for no-sql written entirely in c# that can create databases for use on the xbox 360?

Comment: No sql references sorry for confusion in c# dll source code but Iam specifically looking for dll files. Who keeps putting minus one on my posts. This is a totally acceptable and logical concept.

Comment: I think the library dll that cannot be used on the xbox 360 is system.io.data so if it uses that directly then it will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) is a KeyValue embedded database, essentially the NoSQL equivalent of SQLite. Here is a [C# Tutorial](http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/post/2011/09/03/How+To+Get+Berkeley+DB+5228+And+NET+Examples+Working+In+Visual+Studio+2010+SP1.aspx).

However, I strongly suggest finding an alternative solution to this.  Unless you have a ton of data you're better off holding all your objects in RAM and persisting on a need basis with a JSON, XML, or whatever you want serializer.  LINQ makes it incredibly easy to query in-memory objects the same way you'd query a database.

Comment: I will try it out. I know about the memory that it will take up and yes I will be having a lot of game customzation options and complex data to handle so its better with a db of some kind. Most of the data will be static but also some dynamic data.

Comment: Again if it's just customization things it's better to use your own loading/saving logic. I've updated the post with a link to a c# tutorial.

Comment: Question it appears he is compiling dotnet only libraries? I think that is more to what i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found another possible solution thats open source :
http://ostrivdb.codeplex.com/

The reason for this is coding for xml on xbox byitself sucks and gets too complicated in a massive game project.

I will still click on Dharuns answer because he updated with c# tutorial but I wanted to show what I was talking about.